# Control android media player from lock screen?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

When media player is playing; pause, prev and forward buttons appear on lock screen. How can i  make my media player to listen these buttons? (I'm using Android 2.3.7)

Comment: Check out related topic/discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168046/remote-control-client-for-android). What you are talking about is [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) which only available since API Level 14.

Comment: @yorkw; my device is using version 2.3.7 with Cyanogenmod mode. And i can see the controls when i'm using apps like tuneIn and SoundCloud. Can it be related to Cyanogenmod?

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can't do that unless you write your own lock-screen

Comment: I don't think so, I've seen several apps react to the default "Next" & "Previous" buttons my lockscreen provides. (Speaking of Cyanogenmod/ADWLauncher though).