# For Android 4.2: How to enable lock screen widget for application programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent

As there is an exciting feature in Android 4.2 to place app widget on Lock-Screen.
I have implemented it for my app, but I have to choose my widget to enable it on
lock screen.

But I want to enable and disable widget from my app. That is, if user click on 
check-box then automatically widget for that app should enable on lock-screen and
is user un-check then automatically widget will disable from lock-screen.

please help me.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't change the manifest at runtime. You could make the widget unusuable, but not inaccessible at runtime...

Comment: @StackOverflowException actually you can enable / disable components in the manifest using code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624470/enable-and-disable-a-broadcast-receiver

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: Oh, that's interesting to know, thank you. :)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier or anyone else - are there any examples for how to adapt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624470 to lock-screen widgets?  I know it's possible because the Amazon Prime app dynamically adds a player widget to the lock screen while playing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For folks finding this via Google,
there are some [workarounds](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=44513199) that may work for you or may not, depending on your specific Android configuration.  (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105993) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168046).)

As CommonsWare pointed out, beginning with Android 5.0, a [media style notification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.MediaStyle.html) can be dynamically added to the lock screen.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. The user is welcome to add your lockscreen widget if the user chooses to, from the lockscreen.

Comment: As for adding lock screen widget we have to choose it from lock-screen only. Is there be any Intent that help user to add widget to lock-screen. Or can we use that intent to do this?

Comment: @user2075364: "Is there be any Intent that help user to add widget to lock-screen" -- none that I am aware of, just as there is no such `Intent` for helping a user add an app widget to the home screen.

Comment: Sir is there be any other means to do this, because my app is based on on  this only.

Comment: @user2075364: As I wrote, **this is not possible**.

Comment: Sir can we used any alternative approach for this. I had work on to create an separate activity that get's called on device unlock and device boot-up. I had kept the background of this to transparent but background is not visible correctly.

Comment: Commons, has this changed since you originally answered the question?  The Amazon Prime app now dynamically adds a player widget to the lock screen while playing.  Thanks!

Comment: @cxw: I doubt it. Most likely, that's the media controller (managed by `MediaControlClient`) or a `MediaStyle` lockscreen `Notification`. The latter is new to Android 5.0+, with the former approach deprecated. Many media players use these.